# Xampp port for apache

Tags: apache, xampp, port

so i installed Apache via xampp, but it kept saying the port 80 is being used and I should change the port, so I went into the config and changed the port to 81. 
It was then able to start successfully, but I was wondering is there a downside to this? will anything go wrong or work differently now that I changed to port to 81?

Comment: One downside could be that you would have to access your instance by stating the port number (myserver:81).  Port 80 is the default so when you access myserver, port 80 is understood.

Comment: why is this not an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One downside could be that you would have to access your instance by stating the port number (myserver:81). Port 80 is the default so when you access myserver, port 80 is understood.